# how to use alertify js with django to confirm either ok or cancel

Tags: javascript, django, alertify, alertifyjs

hi i need to use alert message when some wants delete a post ask her/him to delete or cancel

i tried this but this is a default alert browser

```
<button onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete {{obj.title}}')" class="bt mx-auto"><a href="{% url 'posts:post-detail' obj.id %}"><img src="{% static 'icons/delete.svg' %}" alt=""></a></button>
```

i want to use this alert

```
alertify.prompt("are you sure you want to delete ", "{{obj.title}}",
  function(evt, value ){
alertify.success('Ok: ' + value);
  },
function(){
alertify.error('Cancel');
  });
```

[alertify](https://alertifyjs.com/)

but i'm not sure where should i put that script in the template ? i use it inside the button delete , replacing to `confirm()` but seems doesnt work
thanks for helping ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...i want to ask the user when a user wants to remove a post ,( agree
> or disagree ) if selected agree(ok) then the post will be remove , if
> selected disagree (cancel) do nothing with the post

In order to achieve the desired result you need to change a bit your html in order to pass the current element (refer: this keyword) and
like reported in the [examples section](https://alertifyjs.com/examples.html) you can attach to the window object a function called **showAlert**:

```
window.showAlert = function(msg, title, ele) {
    var that = ele;
    alertify.prompt(msg, title,
            function(evt, value){
                ele.closest('div').remove();
            },
            function(){
                // do nothing 
            });
}
```

And change your button to:

```
<button onclick="return showAlert('are you sure you want to delete',  '{{obj.title}}')".....
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.rtl.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.showAlert = function(msg, title, ele) {
    var that = ele;
    alertify.prompt(msg, title,
            function(evt, value){
                ele.closest('div').remove();
            },
            function(){
                // do nothing
            });
}
</script>


<div>
    <p> This is the first post</p>
    <button onclick="return showAlert('are you sure you want to delete',  'post n. 1', this)">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div>
    <p> This is the second post</p>
    <button onclick="return showAlert('are you sure you want to delete',  'post n. 2', this)">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p> This is the third post</p>
    <button onclick="return showAlert('are you sure you want to delete',  'post n. 3', this)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you , but the problem with that script is it remove after i clicked the button , display a pop up then remove the object right after clicked

Comment: it wont let me to choose either ok or cancel , it chose ok permanently

Comment: how it looks like to confirm task ?

Comment: i want to ask the user when a user wants to remove a post ,( agree or disagree ) if selected  agree(ok) then the post will be remove , if selected disagree (cancel) do nothing with the post

Comment: my apologize it doesnt require it , simply i need this https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html but i dont know why it doesnt work in my case

Comment: which error do you see in the browser console? Did you include the library?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: alertify is not defined , yes all files are included

Comment: No, you did not include alertify libraries. See the snippet.